Single frequency light at home
I’m very interested in making some art that’d require me working in single frequency light — specifically the monochromatic light from the sodium vapour bulbs historically used in street lights.
I can find bulbs available to buy and the ballast they apparently need, but I’m unfamiliar with the technology so want to hear about potential dangers or advice for setting up a temporary space at home for working by sodium light.

How would I know if a ballast matches a bulb (beyond a website telling me it does)
Do I need an igniter?
How should I arrange/connect the bulb, the ballast, a possible igniter, and a switch/wall socket together (series/parallel, anything else — I’m aware of how to safely work with other mains electrical systems)
Some online spaces (here and elsewhere) talk about the need to follow particular procedures when turning on/off the bulb (eg. Not turning it back on until it’s cooled; accepting a ~5min warm up period) — what applies here?
Anything else I should know or do while preparing for this?
Are there any “all in one” lamps for these bulbs that’d save me the hassle of planning and building this that I’ve missed?

Many thanks!
(I’m in the UK (240V, 50Hz) if that matters.)

the sad part of story is that high-pressure sodium lamps is not at all momochromatic. High-P, high vapor density lamps are especially constructed for widen it spectrum from single lines to continuous spectum. Only low pressure Na glow lamp will give err,,, a double-frequency light (Sodium have a twin orange spectral line in fact).

What if you just used LEDs? They are not monochromatic in the sense like lasers are but could they have narrow enough spectral peaks?

What output power / lumen do you need?  How close to the Sodium ;lamp colour do you need? Depending on power needs, filtering a wide spectrum lamp may suit. LEDs MAY suit.  Self ballasted metal halide lamp with filtering may suit. Some references say that LP sodium is not now made - at least in the western world.  || Osram made a self ballasted lp sodium BUT discontinued it about 80 years ago !!! :-(

Metal halide spectra here. - add self ballasted to search terms - https://www.google.com/search?q=metal+halide++spectrum&sca_esv=5bc86930ad7b2685&sca_upv=1&udm=2&biw=1536&bih=796&sxsrf=ACQVn0_Q3WLqqp3Pdun54TPRYXmfMEV0qA%3A1713698469220&ei=pfYkZq-EDc2rvr0Pye2B2AM&ved=0ahUKEwjv6omkmNOFAxXNla8BHcl2ADsQ4dUDCBA&uact=5&oq=metal+halide++spectrum&gs_lp=Egxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAiFm1ldGFsIGhhbGlkZSAgc3BlY3RydW0yChAAGIAEGEMYigUyBRAAGIAEMgYQABgHGB4yBhAAGAgYHjIGEAAYCBgeSMY9UPs2WPs2cAF4AJABAJgBuQGgAbkBqgEDMC4xuAEDyAEA-AEBmAIBoALEAZgDAIgGAZIHAzAuMaAH6QI&sclient=gws-wiz-serp

https://www.google.com/imgres?q=self%20ballasted%20metal%20halide%20%20spectrum&imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.shopify.com%2Fs%2Ffiles%2F1%2F0583%2F4522%2F6437%2Ffiles%2FMH-spectrum-jpg.jpg&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fmigrolight.com%2Fblogs%2Fgrow-light-news%2Fthe-best-hid-grow-light&docid=z38K3esFJt4JeM&tbnid=SKI6L5ivfpeVtM&vet=12ahUKEwjv6omkmNOFAxXNla8BHcl2ADsQM3oECE0QAA..i&w=900&h=740&hcb=2&ved=2ahUKEwjv6omkmNOFAxXNla8BHcl2ADsQM3oECE0QAA

https://www.google.com/imgres?q=self%20ballasted%20metal%20halide%20%20spectrum&imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fupload.wikimedia.org%2Fwikipedia%2Fcommons%2Fthumb%2F6%2F67%2FMetal_Halide_Rainbow.png%2F640px-Metal_Halide_Rainbow.png&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikiwand.com%2Fen%2FMetal-halide_lamp&docid=GDBzPimVOBF7iM&tbnid=PRVAiXotwNzGbM&vet=12ahUKEwjv6omkmNOFAxXNla8BHcl2ADsQM3oECHwQAA..i&w=640&h=308&hcb=2&ved=2ahUKEwjv6omkmNOFAxXNla8BHcl2ADsQM3oECHwQAA

It seems you get fairly narrow 595 nm LEDs. Is it essential that the wavelength matches the original low pressure Sodium (589 nm)? (BTW If you can figure out the ballast, it seems there are plenty of LPS bulbs on Amazon etc).

If you want a monochromatic lamp, a low pressure sodium would be my first pick. Long and bulky and only available at relatively high power levels. Is a normal white light source + a narrow filter a viable option for you?

I'm willing to bet OP has been watching youtube - specifically the video from The Corridor Crew, doing the Sodium vapor process.
It could be done with any wavelength really, as long as the light is possible to block/pass with sufficiently sharp bandpass/-stop filters to creat the mattes.

Thank you everyone! It'd be ideal if the spectrum matches — my plan is to use pigments that reflect with different intensities under broad/solar light compared to sodium light. A mosaic on a wall next to a sodium street light which looks different by day and by night.
I'm going to look into using LEDs and filtering — and I'll definitely hunt down a half-decent spectrograph to check the streetlights in question, in case they're no longer monochromatic!

@MrGerber I'm afraid you'd lose that bet — though it sounds like an interesting video!

In that case it's not that you want monochromatic light (which probably wouldn't work well for this), but white-ish light with extremely low CRI. That way the artwork will be visible under both conditions but the colors will change with the illumination. Sodium lamps would be a great choice for this since while they're not very white, people do get used to the color and begin to think of it as off white.

OP should investigate the safety issues carefully, including possible high intensity light damage to eyes and consequences of bulb breakage. If "high pressure" it may be important to contain the bulb in the event of breakage. (I used to work with mercury arc lamps where a sort of violent disassembly during operation was not unknown). Yellow LEDs are a good suggestion. OP hasn't said why exactly a relatively narrow-band spectrum is necessary.

My plan is to use pigments that reflect with different intensities under broad/solar light compared to sodium light; a mosaic on a wall next to a sodium street light which looks different by day and by night. I'd need light with a similar frequency at home to be able to test glazes/pigments for their monochromatic reflectivity.
